# Creating "How can I improve my strategy with X game?" questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Alright what I would like to do is create questions occasionally on the main page that asks how can I improve my game or what was I doing wrong in this match up, more specifically with Starcraft 2 PvP games. I occasionally find myself thinking I've had everything in a certain matchup go perfectly. I've done X and X and X yet for some reason i've still lost. Would it be against the Meta to make questions like these if they included videos and descriptions and etc.

If this isn't against the Meta would it be bad to repeat these types of questions whenever I find myself in this situation, of course as long as it doesn't create duplicate answers. The reason i'm asking this is it may not be a very specific question since games like these usually go to long to really be able to say I followed a specific build or went with a specific strategy.

Almost like a daily "What did I do wrong?" question for example.

Comment: According to the FAQ, if you could have an "entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much". I think pretty much any "How do I do X better?" question is asking too much and is too open-ended. To use an example "How do I do better to survive against Ursa ganking me?". Ban Ursa, Pick Ursa, use wards, have your team tp to you, run away, kite him, use CCs etc.

Comment: @Simon Don't all strategy questions essentially boil down to "How do I do X better?"  I think as long as X is narrowly defined, the questions are fine.

Comment: @SimonL While there is a ton of ways, there is only a handful of common errors to avoid (lack of map control, too aggressive play, f.e.). That could be concisely pointed out - especially in the "what did I do wrong?" setting.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more suited for a dedicated chat than for individual questions.

Individual questions clutter the page with essentially the same "What should I do in this particular situation?" question. This boils down to "Experience. Learn to play.", which is most easily explained in a *discussion* format, with input from various people at a time.

Also: You are likely to have questions in return. "How would I do that?", or "So, you think X would work? Why not Y?". These don't work particularly well with the Q&A stream.

Having a chat with people dedicated to providing a solid idea of how to go about such a thing would be a way to have this instant-discussion resulting in you knowing *exactly* what you did wrong, when you did it wrong and how to improve upon it.

**That said**, I don't think the questions themselves are necessarily off-topic, or *bad*. Nothing wrong with asking, for instance "How to survive against Ursa ganking me? [dota-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota-2)" - or even turning the results of such a chat session into a final Q&A post. I just think *regularly* posting stuff like that with a limited ability to actually discuss them isn't satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

I think that replay analysis would be "too localized" and unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Yes and no. If the question is about a *specific one-of-a-kind thing* ("*This* one match in particular"), I'd agree. But analyzing a *type* of situation wouldn't necessarily be that bad. It all depends on just how the scope of the question is defined.

Comment: either way i dont think i deserved to get downvoted to hell. but w.e